# Is it possible to prove the midpoint theorem with just using alternate-interior(exterior) or corresponding angles?

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof

Here is the statement :

> Let $ABC$ a triangle, $I$ is the midpoint of $[AC]$ and $J$ is the midpoint of $[BC]$. Then the lines $(IJ)$ and $(BC)$ are parallels and $2IJ = BC$.

So is it possible to prove the first part of the statement with just using alternate-interior(exterior) or corresponding angles ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how would that help. I would do it like this:

Triangles $AIJ$ and $ACB$ are similar (sas) with famctor of smiliarty $1:2$.

So $2IJ =BC$ and $IJ||BC$ by Thales theorem.